# Spring Boot 2.1.1 failing to run in Intellij 2018.1

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

My company has our laptops running Intellij 2018.1 Ultimate Edition. 
We have an application that is built on Spring Boot 2.1.1.

When I attempt to run the application, there is no response after hitting the run command. There is no error message, no stack trace, no nothing. All that happens is that the run button gets grayed out and I get no feedback that anything happened.

According to my co-worker, the application works on a different IDE (that I don't have immediate access to).

Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for errors and post them here or report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with `idea.log` attached. Did you try IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.4 available at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html? The issue you have may be already fixed. It's always a good idea to update to the current release before reporting any issues.

Comment: I will give that a look, I can't exactly update to any version I want because of my business's security, but I do see 2018.2 was approved. I will see if using that might work.

Comment: The update to 2018.2 worked. I would thank you CrazyCoder, but you are too Crazy for me. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue should be resolved by updating to a [recent IntelliJ IDEA version](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html).

If it still doesn't help, please [contact the support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new) team with the [logs attached](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).